# SQLite Operations in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have worked with SQLite on android before but this is the first time I'm handling quite a lot of data.

When my activity is opened for the first time it downloads the data from the server.  I use google's volley library so I assume I don't need to run it in an async task.

My issue however seems to be with saving the data into sqlite db, rows returned for that single request are between 500-1000.  From that point on anytime new data is added on the server I update the app using FCM so no issue with that.

While saving all those records I want to display a circular progress bar and message to the user explaining to them what is happening however I have noticed that my app freezes for 10-15 seconds while the data is being saved.  By freezes I mean the progress bar stops moving and activities components and views are not loaded until that process is done.

So my question now is this, what is the right way of doing this so it doesn't interfere with the UI thread allowing me to have the views loaded and a smoother progress bar animation before the operation has completed.

I tried using an async task but noticed no change in performance:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bus_schedules);

    new SaveDataAsync().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[]) null);
}

private class SaveDataAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getSchedules();
        return null;
    };
}

protected void getSchedules() {
    showProgress(true)
    mScheduleReq.all(new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                JSONArray schedules = response;

                for (int c = 0; c < schedules.length(); c++) {
                    JSONObject schedule = schedules.getJSONObject(c);

                    mSchedulesDat.save(new TravelSchedule(
                            schedule.getInt("id"),
                            schedule.getInt("company_id"),
                            schedule.getInt("route_id"),
                            schedule.getString("class"),
                            (float) schedule.getDouble("fare"),
                            schedule.getString("weekday"),
                            schedule.getString("reporting_time"),
                            schedule.getString("departure_time"),
                            schedule.getInt("by_bus"),
                            schedule.getInt("by_plane")
                    ));

                    // Saving Extras
                    JSONArray extras = schedule.getJSONArray("extras");
                    for (int k=0; k < extras.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject extra = extras.getJSONObject(k);

                        mExtrasDat.save(new Extra(
                                extra.getInt("id"),
                                schedule.getInt("id"),
                                extra.getString("category"),
                                extra.getString("name"),
                                (float) extra.getDouble("price"),
                                extra.getString("description"),
                                extra.getString("company")
                        ));
                    }

                    // This will prevent fetching all data again from server the next time
                    mAppDat.save("initialised_travel_schedules", String.valueOf(true));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Hide progress bar
            showProgress(false);

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // Hide progress bar
            showProgress(false);

            // Parse and display network error response
            showNetworkResponse(mContext, error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need an AsyncTask for SQLite, sounds like. If using FCM, why not Firebase database?

Comment: @user3718908 Just one suggestion that if you can try to use AsyncTask with LoganSquare for inputstream parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your work on the UI/main thread, which is blocking all other updates to the UI. Any heavy processing that needs to be done should be handled in the background, either with a loader, AsyncTask, or (preferably) RxJava.

If you decide to go the reactive/RxJava route, I would suggest trying out https://github.com/square/sqlbrite. This will allow you to subscribe/unsubscribe to your query and insert operations in the background and post results to the view asynchronously (Activity, Fragment, etc.) as data comes in.

[The official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) have a pretty good overview about how threading works on Android if you want to dig deeper.

Comment: Okay I did try using with an ASYNC task but there was no difference so I reverted to my previous code.  Maybe I was not doing something right.

Comment: Post a code sample with your question, you probably did something incorrectly.

Comment: Question in my activty's `onCreate` I have a variable `context = getApplicationContext` which I pass in my ASYNC task to my SQLite functions, could this have anything to do with why I didn't see a change?

Comment: @user3718908 `YourActivity.this` is the context. You don't need to call `getApplicationContext`. But no, that wouldn't block the UI.